# pandas-change order of rows to make a value evenly distributed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
A B C
-----
1 3 q 
2 2 q
3 6 q
4 7 q
5 8 q
3 8 q
1 3 s 
2 2 s
3 8 s
```

I want the rows with 's' to be 'evenly' distributed in the dataframe like below:

```
A B C
-----
2 2 s
1 3 q 
2 2 q
3 6 q
3 8 s
4 7 q
5 8 q 
3 8 q
1 3 s
```

How to deal with it?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please try it and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order of s is not important then try this one ?

```
A=len(df1)+len(df2)
df1.index=(list(range(0, A,4)))
df2.index=list(set(range(0, A))-set(range(0, A,4)))
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0).sort_index()


df
Out[147]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  3  s
1  1  3  q
2  2  2  q
3  3  6  q
4  2  2  s
5  4  7  q
6  5  8  q
7  3  8  q
8  3  8  s
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the order of the rows in every 'category':

```
df1 = df[df.C == 'q']
df2 = df[df.C == 's']

spacing = int(len(df1) / (len(df2) - 1))
df2ind = range(0, (len(df2) - 1) * (spacing + 1) + 1, spacing + 1)

df1ind = [range(i + 1, i + 1 + spacing) for i in df2ind]
df1ind = [i for l in df1ind for i in l][:len(df1)]

df1.index = df1ind
df2.index = df2ind
df = pandas.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

In: df
Out: 
   A  B  C
0  1  3  s
1  1  3  q
2  2  2  q
3  3  6  q
4  2  2  s
5  4  7  q
6  5  8  q
7  3  8  q
8  3  8  s
```