# evenly arrange dataframe rows based on the values in a given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that will be produced with a random amount of rows with differing amounts in the district column. I would like to re-arrange it in a way that evenly distributes based on the values in the district columns. Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
Region District  A   B ...
--------------------------
  x      alpha   1   4 ...
  x      alpha   2   3 ...
  x      alpha   3   4 ...
  x      alpha   4   3 ...
  x      alpha   5   4 ...
  x      alpha   6   4 ...
  x      alpha   7   3 ...
  x      alpha   8   4 ...
  x      alpha   9   3 ...
  x      alpha   10  4 ...
  x      bravo   11  3 ...
  x      bravo   12  4 ...
  x      bravo   13  3 ...
  x      bravo   14  3 ...
  x    charlie   15  4 ...
  x    charlie   16  3 ...
  x    charlie   17  4 ...
  x    charlie   18  3 ...
  x    charlie   19  4 ...
  x    charlie   20  3 ...
  x    charlie   21  4 ...
  x    charlie   22  3 ...
  x    charlie   23  4 ...
```

I would like to make it look something like this:

```
Region District  A   B ...
--------------------------
  x      alpha   1   4 ...
  x      alpha   2   3 ...
  x      bravo   11  3 ...
  x    charlie   15  4 ...
  x    charlie   16  3 ...
  x      alpha   3   4 ...
  x      alpha   4   3 ...
  x      bravo   12  4 ...
  x    charlie   17  4 ...
  x    charlie   18  3 ...
  x      alpha   5   4 ...
  x      alpha   6   4 ...
  x      bravo   13  3 ...
  x    charlie   19  4 ...
  x    charlie   20  3 ...
  x      alpha   7   3 ...
  x      alpha   8   4 ...
  x      bravo   14  3 ...
  x    charlie   21  4 ...
  x    charlie   22  3 ...
  x      alpha   9   3 ...
  x      alpha   10  4 ...
  x    charlie   21  4 ...
  x    charlie   22  3 ...
  x    charlie   23  4 ...
```

Each of the methods i have tried gives me a length mismatch error

Comment: what exactly have you tried that didn't work, also, could you be more specific on the condition to be sorted by ?

Comment: this is a tough question to answer with out more context - but you will probably go some way by creating a group rank e.g. `df.groupby('district').rank()` type of approach then sort by that rank or multiple ranks.

Comment: I tried the method used at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767107/pandas-change-order-of-rows-to-make-a-value-evenly-distributed.  I already have each district grouped together as seen in the first table. What i am wanting to do is basically evenly spread out each of the districts. the process i am wanting to apply to the dataframe will iterate through each row and I am wanting to affect all the districts evenly with respect to their size. The way they are spread out will change over time because there will be varying number of rows per district.

Comment: When i tried the method at the above link i got this error:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 118 elements, new values have 138 elements

Answer (score 0):

How about solving it like this:

```
#seperate the df's for each group in district
dic = {k:v.reset_index() for k,v in df.groupby('District', as_index=False)}

#get length of smallest group
smallest_group = df['District'].value_counts().min()

# change index of each df 
for k,v in dic.items():
    divisor = len(v) // smallest_group
    v.index = [x//divisor for x in v.index]

# concat the data and sort it by new index 
out = pd.concat([*dic.values()], axis=0).rename_axis('idx').sort_values(['idx', 'District'])
print(out)
```

Output:

```
     index Region District   A  B
idx                              
0        0      x    alpha   1  4
0        1      x    alpha   2  3
0       10      x    bravo  11  3
0       14      x  charlie  15  4
0       15      x  charlie  16  3
1        2      x    alpha   3  4
1        3      x    alpha   4  3
1       11      x    bravo  12  4
1       16      x  charlie  17  4
1       17      x  charlie  18  3
2        4      x    alpha   5  4
2        5      x    alpha   6  4
2       12      x    bravo  13  3
2       18      x  charlie  19  4
2       19      x  charlie  20  3
3        6      x    alpha   7  3
3        7      x    alpha   8  4
3       13      x    bravo  14  3
3       20      x  charlie  21  4
3       21      x  charlie  22  3
4        8      x    alpha   9  3
4        9      x    alpha  10  4
4       22      x  charlie  23  4
```